# images in html img tag become blurred on my iPhone application

Tags: iphone, html, ios, image

My iOS Application contains some .html files, .jpg files in project itself. And show them via webView.
My image files are high-resolution but when it added to html files with  tag and check them with iOS simulator zoom in... images became blurred so that I can't read text on them.

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<head>
<title></title>
<meta name="viewport" charset="utf-8" content="initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=20.0; user-scalable=yes">
<link rel="stylesheet"  href="style.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="m.ritz.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css" />
<script src="jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="scrollview.js"></script>
</head> 

<body>          
 <img src="tong.png" width="500"/>
</body>                         
</html>
```

My code has nothing special... But I can't find the reason... help me~

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You appear to be setting a specific width (resolution) for the image within the HTML. If the stored image has a greater resolution than that requested, the browser will down-sample the image to the requested resolution. This process can introduce image artefacts, blurring etc.

Try creating an image file which is equal in resolution to that which you wish to display. This should remove the need for the browser to reps ample the image leaving you with a nice sharp image.